# issue passing URL from json config file to python script

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm currently writing a small python script to monitor all Urls within my teams pool of web apps. I have a python script that basically runs in an infinite loop and will check the urls every 60 min. My issue lies in pulling my url's from my json config. for some reason I cannot use a url that has the adress:port and extension thereafter

My python script or function is as follows(partial) and basically bombs out when it gets to  the connection portion conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(website). The issue lies in reading URLs in this format ("url": "zardev0201230265:7778/apt/server/login/#")

```
def monitor():
  import httplib
  import logging
  import json
  import os
  p = os.getpid()

#Basic config for / displays what will appear in log file
#Open Json config file and use data function to load and read the file
  logging.basicConfig(filename='SalesTriggerCHECK.log', format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', level=logging.INFO)
  with open('htppchecklogconfig.json') as json_data_file:
   data = json.load(json_data_file)

#Declare i as counter to iterate through json list, range will be set to length of the list
#Assign data for current iteration for server/category and URL to variables
  for i in range(len(data["application_details"])):
   server = (data["application_details"][i]["server"])
   application = (data["application_details"][i]["application"])
   category = (data["application_details"][i]["category"])
   website = (data["application_details"][i]["url"])

#Connection settings that are required to make a connection request to check URL
#The data function is used in conjunction with the counter(i) to find the URL in the Json file
#Res variable stores response from connection request / if statement checks for status 200 for ok
#We can get the response code and reason using the the get response function when make the connection
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(website)
   conn.request("HEAD", "/index.html")
   res = conn.getresponse()
```

My JSON config file is as follows:

```
{
    "application_details": [
          {
            "server": "Server120",
            "application": "sales application",
            "category": "DEV",
            "url": "zardev0201230265:7778/apt/server/login/#"
        },
        {
            "server": "Server130",
            "application": "Dashboard-Hangfire",
            "category": "DEV",
            "url": "zardev0201230297:7779"
        }


    ]
```

error details

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\app\httpchecklog.py", line 50, in <module>
    monitor()
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\app\httpchecklog.py", line 33, in monitor
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(website)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 751, in __init__
    (self.host, self.port) = self._get_hostport(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 792, in _get_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '7778/apt/server/login/#'
```

any advice around this would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the exception: nonnumeric port. The HTTPConnection class interprets everything after the ':' as the port, in your case: '7778/apt/server/login/#'. This can only be numeric. If you change it to '7778', the exception shouldn't occur.

The available parameters can be found in the python docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html

Comment: thanks for the response, I gathered thats the issue, i need a way around it cause the it doesn't pick up the url as alive if i leave everything after the port number out

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry that interpreted the question wrong and underestimated what you already found out. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience with the httplib, so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Thanks again Michel, really appreciate the effort, maybe ill try and use something othwe than httplib.